# if statement befor creating a node

Tags: 7, nodes

I need to set an `if` statement before creating a specific content type's node.

How can I stop the creation process if the condition returns false, and get back to the creation page with error message to let the user to correct the wrong value.

Is there a function to get it work?

Comment: Does the data you need to validate come from a field?

Comment: not exactly i want to test if there is a match from field value in creating node with field value from the referenced node.  
if there is a match i want to stop the creation.

Comment: Either of the answers below should help you with that. You might also want to look at the [Field Validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module, in case you can do what you need to with that (no code necessarily required).

Comment: @Clive man..I use Field Validation on most of my sites..I can't believe I forgot it :@

Comment: @Chapabu It's friday, these things happen ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [`hook_node_validate`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7).

> Perform node validation before a node is created or updated.
>
> This hook is invoked from node_validate(), after a user has has
>   finished editing the node and is previewing or submitting it. It is
>   invoked at the end of all the standard validation steps, and after the
>   type-specific hook_validate() is invoked.
>
> To indicate a validation error, use form_set_error().

Something *like* the following would work:

```
function mymodule_node_validate($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'mynodetype') {
    if ($node->myfieldsvalue != 'what it should') {
      form_set_error('field_name', t('Your error message'));
    }
  }
}
```

References:

[`hook_node_validate`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7)

[`form_set_error`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, seems a perfectly good answer to me

Comment: I thought so...my personal preference would be to use `hook_node_validate` over Rules as this would give me more flexibility and keep everything in code.  Everyone's a winner.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.  For example, you can write a rule that fires on the event *Before saving new content* with the **condition** *data comparison* (on the relevant field's value) and an **action** of *print status message*.  You can of course further customize this to get it to do exactly what you want.